# Why when I run a job from Dataprep to GBQ the result have only one row?

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep, data-preprocessing

I added a dataset in Dataprep and made my recipe as aways, but when I run the job the table created in BigQuery has just only one row. In Dataprep the preview of the table is correct (with all my 3000+ rows).

[image: Recipe with the preview table correctly!][image: Resulted BigQuery table]

Comment: So it worked previously but you encounter this issue today. If you will execute this job once more you will get the same result? Does this dataset contains different values then previously? Did you get any error report?

Comment: At this dataset it doesn't work, if I run again the same result will be expected. No errors are presented.

Comment: So other datasets works correctly and only this one is affected? Could you also check if you didn't hit any quota?